# How to format a mixed Character String to number

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hdp

I have Geospatial Co-ordinate in coded format like (0305463N , 0962754W ) need to convert it into 30.5463, -96.2754.

So think there three column in a table

ID : 123456
Lat : 0305463N
Long : 0962754W

and I need to convert it to

ID : 123456
Lat : 30.5463
Long : -96.2754

Rules need to be dependent upon how it is ending either in N or W as I co-ordinates are only in USA that will cover all the cases but any general solution will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually nothing as of yet through hiveql i am thinking using java or python to convert it .....